# Integral over $S^{n-1}$

Tags: integration, integral-operators, spherical-geometry, sphere-packing

What is the values of  the following integral:

$$\int_{w \in S^{n-1}} e^{i\lambda< x,w  >} dw.$$
where $\lambda\in\Bbb R, i^2=-1,x\in\Bbb R^n;<,>$ the inner product scalar on $\Bbb R^n$  and $S^{n-1}$ the unit sphere of $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: This is the Fourier transform of the of the surface measure at the point $\lambda x$ and can be expressed through Bessel functions. See Stein-Weiss, Introduction to Fourier Analysis, pag 154

Comment: Without loss of generality you may orient the vector $w$ along the $x_1$ axis, then
$$\int_{w \in S^{n-1}} e^{i\lambda< x,w  >} dw=\frac{2 \pi ^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}{\Gamma \left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)}\int_0^\pi e^{i\lambda\cos\theta} \sin^{n-2}\theta\, d\theta$$
$$\qquad\qquad=(2 \pi )^{n/2} \lambda^{1-\frac{n}{2}}J_{\frac{n}{2}-1}(\lambda).$$